# Using Javascript to print labels to client-side DYMO printer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dymo

I have the following code, after multiple iterations. None of which work. I got this based on examples directly from DYMO as well as other questions posted here. Still nothing is working. When I click the buttons, no reaction whatsoever.

```
<input id="btnUnitPrint" type="button" value="Print Unit Label" onclick = "printunitLabel()"/><br />
<input id="btnOrderPrint" type="button" value="Print Order Label" onclick = "printorderLabel()"/><br />
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function printunitLabel() {

        var printer = dymo.label.framework.getLabelWriterPrinters()[0].modelName;
        printerName = printer.name; 

        var label = DYMO.Label.Framework.Label.Open("UnitLabel.label");
        var company = document.getElementById('<%= txtcompany.Text %>').value;
        var customer = document.getElementById('<%= txtcustomer.Text %>').value;
        var serial = document.getElementById('<%= txtserial.Text %>').value;
        var unit = document.getElementById('<%= txtunit_manuf.Text + txtunit_model.Text %>').value;
        var warranty = document.getElementById('<%= ddlWarranty.Text %>').value;
        label.SetObjectText("lblcompany", company);
        label.SetObjectText("lblcustomer", customer);
        label.SetObjectText("lblserial", serial);
        label.SetObjectText("lblunit", unit);
        label.SetObjectText("txtWarranty", warranty);

        label.print(printerName);
    }  
    function printorderLabel() {

        var printer = dymo.label.framework.getLabelWriterPrinters()[0].modelName;
        printerName = printer.name;

        var label = DYMO.Label.Framework.Label.Open("OrderLabel.label");
        var company = document.getElementById('<%= txtcompany.Text %>').value;
        var customer = document.getElementById('<%= txtcustomer.Text %>').value;
        var order = document.getElementById('<%= txtorder_id.Text %>').value;
        label.SetObjectText("lblcompany", company);
        label.SetObjectText("lblcustomer", customer);
        label.SetObjectText("lblorder", order);
        label.Print(printer);

        label.print(printerName);
    } 
</script>
```

UPDATE, this panel contains all of the variables I am looking to pass to the label template.

```
<asp:Panel ID="confirmation_panel" runat="server" Height="457px" Style="margin-right: 0px" Width="1040px" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="2px">
    <br />
    <table style="width: 469px; height: 385px;">
        <tr>
            <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 1231px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblorder_id" runat="server" Text="Order ID:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 34px; width: 326px;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtorder_id" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="231px" Height="22px" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 1231px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblunit_id" runat="server" Text="Unit ID:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 34px; width: 326px;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtunit_id" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="231px" Height="22px" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 1231px">
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Company Name:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 34px; width: 326px;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtcompany" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="231px" Height="22px" NullDisplayText=""></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 1231px">
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Client Name:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 34px; width: 326px;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtcustomer" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="231px" Height="22px" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 1231px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblunit_manuf" runat="server" Text="Unit Manufacturer:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 34px; width: 326px;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtunit_manuf" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="231px" Height="22px" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 1231px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblunit_model" runat="server" Text="Unit Model:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 34px; width: 326px;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtunit_model" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="231px" Height="22px" ForeColor="Red"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 1231px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblserial" runat="server" Text="Serial Number:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 34px; width: 326px;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtserial" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="231px" Height="22px" ForeColor="Red"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 1231px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblWUserial" runat="server" Text="Whole Unit Serial Number:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 34px; width: 326px;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtWUserial" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Width="231px" Height="22px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="modal-sm" style="width: 1231px">
                <asp:Label ID="lblwarranty" runat="server" Text="Warranty Status:"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 34px; width: 326px;">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWarranty" Width="231px" Height="22px" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Warranty Expired</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Warranty Active</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>N/A</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Don't, no need to feel that way. Could you add the HTML with the `company`, `customer`, `serial`, etc. to your question. And let's remove some of these comments make some room for new ones. ;)

Comment: I updated the question with the HTML you are asking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to look at the most recent documentation, but there is so little and it all seems very outdated. Below here I've made an example of what your form (basically) should look like, wrapped in a `<form>` element.

You are going to need the latest version of the `dymo.label.framework.js` framework to load the functionality of DYMO into the browser.

The code below basically does the same thing as what you tried above with the key difference that it is now asynchronous, meaning it won't block the code when it tries to calculate expensive tasks, which is good!

The creation of the `label` with `dymo.label.framework.open` is still kind of a guess. I've seen examples with `dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml` and one with an image so it is up to you which one is appropriate for you. Again with limited documentation it is hard to know what it does.

The example below is based on [this article](https://developers.dymo.com/2016/08/08/dymo-label-web-service-faq/) on the DYMO dev site. I hope that this will

```
<form id="label-form">
  <input type="text" name="company">
  <input type="text" name="customer">
  <input type="text" name="serial">
  <input type="text" name="unit">
  <input type="text" name="warranty">
  <input id="btnUnitPrint" type="button" value="Print Unit Label"/>
  <input id="btnOrderPrint" type="button" value="Print Order Label"/>
</form>
```

```
<!-- Look for the latest dymo.label.framework.js script and place it here -->
<script src="dymo.label.framework.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script>
const labelForm = document.getElementById('label-form');
const printUnitButton = document.getElementById('btnUnitPrint');
const printOrderButton = document.getElementById('btnOrderPrint');

function startupCode() {
   
   // Gets all the printers, asynchronously.
   dymo.label.framework.getPrintersAsync().then(function(printers) {

     // Check for available printers.
     if (printers.length === 0) {
       throw Error('No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers.');
     }
      
     // Select the first printer in the list that has the
     // type of "LabelWriterPrinter" and use that as the printer.
     const printer = printers.find(printer => printer.printerType === "LabelWriterPrinter");

     // Get the name of that printer.
     const printerName = printer.name;

     // Create the label.
     // You'll need to check on your own if this is the way to
     // properly create the label.
     const label = dymo.label.framework.open('OrderLabel.label');

     const printUnit = function printUnit() {
       const formData = new FormData(labelForm);
       const customer = formData.get('customer');
       const company = formData.get('company');
       const serial = formData.get('serial');
       const unit = formData.get('unit');
       const warranty = formData.get('warranty');
       label.setObjectText('lblcompany', company);
       label.setObjectText('lblcustomer', customer);
       label.setObjectText('lblserial', serial);
       label.setObjectText('lblunit', unit);
       label.setObjectText('txtWarranty', warranty);
       label.print(printerName);
     }

     const printOrder = function printOrder() {
       const formData = new FormData(labelForm);
       const customer = formData.get('customer');
       const company = formData.get('company');
       const order = formData.get('order');
       label.setObjectText('lblcompany', company);
       label.setObjectText('lblcustomer', customer);
       label.setObjectText('lblorder', order);
       label.print(printerName);
     }

     // Print unit on printUnitButton click.
     printUnitButton.addEventListener('click', printUnit);
 
     // Print order on printOrderButton click.
     printOrderButton.addEventListener('click', printOrder);   

  });

}

function frameworkInitHelper() {
  dymo.label.framework.init(startupCode);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to try this first thing in the morning and will update if it works! :)

Comment: I am getting these errors in the Console. `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:44331/OrderUnitStatus' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.latest.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`  as well as  `Uncaught ReferenceError: printunitLabel is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (OrderUnitStatus:316)`  and  `Uncaught ReferenceError: printorderLabel is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (OrderUnitStatus:317)`.

Comment: I'm still unsure if I'm doing the right thing where you said `<!-- Look for the latest dymo.label.framework.js script and place it here -->`. I replaced that text with this `<script src="http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.latest.js type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>`

Comment: Remove the `http:` part from the string in the script. Your site is HTTPS which means that it requires all subsequent scripts to also be downloaded with HTTPS instead of HTTP. Removing the protocol from the string will result the browser in checking if there is a HTTPS version of the script or otherwise fallback to HTTP.

Comment: You have 2 `onclick` attributes in your HTML. Remove these from your inputs. The script I provided above uses `addEventListener` from the script to do the same thing. I did this because I think that this is the way you should use event listeners from now on. It will keep your HTML and JavaScript separated and make it easier to listen for events.

Comment: I did find where I had the duplicate `onclick` in the input, removed that and no longer getting the `Uncaught Reference Error`. Now I am just getting this error in console `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: I'm not sure if you could find anything different but I have tried all kinds of variations of the source URL for the DYMO JS library and I cant get connected to anything. I am only seeing the `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error. I am at a loss as to where to go from here. I called DYMO and they hung up on me because I don't think you can easily reach developer support by phone and they just couldn't help me. I appreciate your assistance with this issue but I can't even determine if this is a functional solution or not.